# What if Eve knows the value of $S$ in digital signiture?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography

I have a question about the security of the digital signiture protocol if Eve knows the value of $S$, $C$ or $d_A$.

I think that digital signiture is not less secure if she know S, but it is less secure if she knows C or $d_A$. Am I right? Why?

- 1ste person: Alice
- 2nd person: Eve
- 3rd person: Bob

[image]

Comment: I dont know the RSA authentification

Comment: Now who is Eve?

Comment: Just added it, sorry!

Comment: What are $S,C,d_A$? Those might be some standard notation, but I don't work in the field.

Comment: S is the signiture of a message, C is the challenge, e the public key, d the private key. it's simular to RSA

Comment: What is the protocol **exactly**? The picture does not explain it very well. Who sends a challenge to whom? Does rabbit send $C$ to Alice? It's not in the diagram. Alice gets $C$ and signs it and rabbit verifies it? Then it's triavially broken by an active attacker.